# How to link to PETSc from a C++ (with armadillo) code?

Tags: c++, armadillo, petsc

I have a piece of C++ code (main.cpp) which uses armadillo to prepare a very LARGE sparse matrix and its r.h.s, to be solved like x = A\b.

**Problem**: In armadillo, no parallel-iterative-linear sparse solver exists. And I am thinking to consider PETSc, which has many capable solvers. But, I have no clue how to link it to my main.cpp code.

Hints:
1- My code is serial, however, armadillo uses a threaded process.
2- PETSc is MPI-based parallel, and in C.

How can I link/compile/run PETSc from my main.cpp? Any help is well appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

By default, PETSc will build a single library. Suppose that you installed the package, rather than remaining in the source tree. In order to compile, you need -I/path/to/petsc/include, and then to link you need -L/path/to/petsc/lib -lpetsc.